# Error with Julia using Atom

Tags: julia

I have a lot of problems with Julia since started. I am new in programming and new in Julia so please excuse my misunderstanding. 
I wanted to plot in real time with Julia ([This question solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281135/real-time-plotting-with-julia)). At this time I was using Jupiter kernel which limits the amount of data that can be transferred to the browser so I switched recently to Atom to try to plot in real time but I am having a lot of trouble.

Now, when I try to execute any code in atom, I have this error message :

> Julia 0.5.1 [1m[31mERROR: LoadError: ZMQ.StateError("Address already
>   in use") in bind(::ZMQ.Socket, ::String)  at
>   /Users/myname/.julia/v0.5/ZMQ/src/ZMQ.jl:321 in
>   init(::Array{String,1}) at
>   /Users/myname/.julia/v0.5/IJulia/src/init.jl:77 in
>   include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488 in
>   include_from_node1(::String) at
>   /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
>   in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:265 in _start() at
>   ./client.jl:321 in _start() at
>   /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
>   while loading /Users/myname/.julia/v0.5/IJulia/src/kernel.jl, in
>   expression starting on line 8 [0m

I am more than lost in this error message, I tried to look on google but does not find any similar error.

Could anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Your heading says "Atom" and you've marked it "atom-editor", but why do you think it relates to Atom? ZMQ is not a dependency of Atom/Juno, but it is a dependency of Jupyter (and in fact, the error is called by IJulia if you look carefully at the error message). I don't know why IJulia is even being called in an Atom session, are you somehow calling IJulia in your script?. Otherwise it sounds more like something is wrong in your Julia installation.

Comment: I thought this was an Atom error because I dont get this type of errors using Jupyter notebook. I took it off though, thank you for your precision. I dont think that my script is calling IJulia. 
I think there might be something wrong with both my Julia installation and Atom installation. When trying to do 1+1 in Atom I obtain "Invalid HMAC signature". Would you reckon to delete everything and install everything again?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would try. Did you install in a non-standard way?

Comment: I dont really know what would be a standard way, I know that I have been struggling to install it at the beginning. And I had lots of complication since I installed the new version of macOS Sierra. I will try to desinstall and reinstall everything.I beginning with Julia, moreover I dont understand much about how computers work but I really want to learn, first to feel less lost in front of a problem and have a clearer picture.But I just could not find any "beginners explanation" about the basis on how Julia works,what is the link with ZMQ,homebrew...how could I start to understand all this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/ ? There's quite a lot to read but I find it very well explained